# Make hibernate collections a HashMap instead of List or Set

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there any way to make hibernate OneToMany collections a Map of id to entity, rather than List or Set?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

take a look on @[MapKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKey.html) JPA anotation...
can't test it right now, but it's should be something like

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
@MapKey
private Map<Integer, Order> orders;
```